# Where does force act in two parallel current carrying conductors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, electric-current, magnetic-moment

F=ILB.so consider length as 5 m and I as 2 ampere and B as 5 T.so the force is 50 N.does this 50 N act at one point or equally applied on full length like pressure.So what does force/length in this signify as the numerical gives 2 N for 1 meter.if 50 N acts on every length how can 2N act at 1 meter.

Comment: Please clarify or be a bit more specific

Comment: my doubt is if the force is acting at one point or uniformly acting i e 50N on full length 1m.